# PHP Table doesn't show data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I wrote this code and after click submit button it won't show table with data. I have checked if nazwa1 contain some string but it won't show nothing. I am new in PHP and HTML so I haven't certainty that is good code. I read some web sites and I think my code looks good.  I was looking answer everywhere and I found nothing. Thanks for help.

```
        <?php

                $link=mysqli_connect(connect_data);

                    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                    printf("Nie udało się połączyć: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
                    exit();};

        echo "<div class=\"row\">";
            $query = "SELECT Distinct Nazwa FROM vDane ";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                echo "<div class=\"col-xl-12 marginesy\">";
                echo "<div class=\"row\">";
                    echo "<div class=\"col-xl-3\">";
                        echo "<select name=\"nazwa1\" class=\"form-control form-control-sm\"  placeholder=\"nazwa1\">";
                        echo "<option value=\"Pracownik\">Pracownik</option>";
                        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                            echo "<option value=".$row['Nazwa'].">" .$row['Nazwa']. "</option>";

                        }
                        echo "</select>";
                    echo "</div>";
            $query = "SELECT Distinct Date FROM vDane ";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                    echo "<div class=\"col-xl-3\">";
                        echo "<select class=\"form-control form-control-sm\" name=\"Date\" placeholder=\"Date\">";
                        echo "<option value=\"Data\">Data</option>";
                        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                            echo "<option value=".$row['Date'].">" .$row['Date']. "</option>";

                        }                       
                        echo "</select>";
                        //$first_option = $_POST(['Date']);

                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "<div class=\"col-xl-3\">";
                        echo "<select class=\"form-control form-control-sm\" name=\"data\" placeholder=\"Data\">";
                        echo "</select>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "<div class=\"col-xl-3\">";
                        echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">";
                        echo "<input class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm \" type=\"submit\" name=\"find\" value=\"Submit\">";

                        echo "</select>";
                    echo "</div>";


                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class=\"row tabela\"  style=\"overflow: scroll !important\">";           
                echo "<table class=\"table table-bordered table-md\">";
                echo "<thead>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<th>Imię Nazwisko</th>";
                        echo "<th>Data</th>";
                        echo "<th>Godzina</th>";
                        echo "<th>Wej/wyj</th>";            
                    echo "</tr>";
                echo "</thead>";
                echo "<tbody>";
                if(isset($_POST['find'])){

                    $second_option = $_POST['nazwa1'];
                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">";
                        echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"alert-link\">".$second_option."</a>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    if($second_option == "Pracownik"){
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM vDane ";
                        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

                    }
                    if($second_option != "Pracownik"){
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM vDane WHERE Nazwa = $second_option";
                        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);         
                    }

                        foreach($row as $row){
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<th scope=\"row\">".$row['Nazwa']."</th>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['Date']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['Time']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['Scan_ID']."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";       
                        }
                    echo "</tbody>";
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo "</form>";



                    }
                mysqli_close($link);

                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting square brackets or backticks around your table name.

```
    $query = "SELECT [Distinct Nazwa] FROM vDane ";
    $query = "SELECT `Distinct Nazwa` FROM vDane ";
```

It looks to me like it's trying to select "Distinct" as your table, instead of "Distinct Nazwa". According to a couple Stack Overflow questions, one of the above should fix it if that's the issue.

Comment: But it isn't my problem in droplist i have data from database but when i choose one it isnt shown in a table.

Comment: It looks like it wont go to the second if wherw it checks $second_option, but i dont now why it looks good to me

Comment: Try taking this and putting it above the select statement (right below div class='col-xl-3')

        echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">";

It looks to me like it isn't counting the select statement as part of the form, so it isn't setting it for $second_option.

Comment: Wow, that was a mess. If that's convoluted, let me elaborate: Make sure your <form></form> is encompassing all of the form, including your <select> tags, and tell me if that fixes it.